# What is the category of a phrase like "I'll take it from here"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, terminology

- "I'll take it from here"
- "If you don't mind"
- "Don't mind if you do"
- "I'm on board"
- etc

As a non-native speaker, I found such phrases extremely useful, and they lighten up the conversation in a friendly way unless overused (e.g., "I'm on board" for the millionth time).

What are these called exactly? Is there a category? It's not idiom (I looked it up), and I can't say it's "general speech" since it's used the same way all the time in various contexts. I don't think they're jargon, either.

They've been a real help when talking to my mostly older coworkers without the crude jokes or comments I make with friends.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Thank you, this is a nice first question. Even though you got the gist of ELU already, you can take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good questions.

Comment: I appreciate your help by adding the `single-word-requests` tag, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I admit, I'm a bit uncertain about how I should approach this question, but I think we can do better.

Comment: Are you not looking for a word that names that category of phrases?

Comment: Not necessarily a *single* word. It could be something like "work lingo". But I may be taking it too literally, oops.

Comment: This could come under the umbrella of *small-talk*.

Comment: @user1164937 I think "lingo" is the best choice actually - "office lingo" perhaps.  Want to work your comment into an answer?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your category really is. They could be considered idioms (contrary to what you think), clichés, or phaticisms. They don't exactly lighten a conversation meaninglessly because they each have their own distinct meaning. Also, it's "Don't mind if _I_ do" (to be said for when someone offers you something and you accept); your sentence is nonsensical in any social context. Please edit and clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest term I can think of to describe this kind of construction is [**cliché**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cliche):

> **cliché** *n*
>   1. (Linguistics) a word or expression that has lost much of its force through overexposure, as for example the phrase: *it's got to get worse before it gets better.*

There is probably some difference, though, since the examples you cite are so common they may not even rise to the standard of cliché. Nevertheless, they are expressions that have lost their force through overexposure, so they do fit the definition.

In fact, these expressions may have lost so much force they could fall under the aegis of [**phatic communication**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phatic)

> **phatic** *adj*
>   Of or relating to communication used to perform a social function rather than to convey information or ideas.

<sup><sub>citations from TheFreeDictionaryOnline</sub></sup>

Answer (score -1):

*social niceties*

*polite formulas*

*set phrases* (this means *standard phrases*)

*pleasantries*